# Dog is having scabs show up after staples

Tags: dogs, surgery

[image]My dog got staples & stitches in his foot about 6 days ago & the bandage kept moving so I have to keep changing it. The bottom half looks great but the top half looks irritated & blistered & I’m not sure if it’s infected or not.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this looks fine, but if you are really concerned, you should reach out to your vet.

My dog recently had to get staples as well (back in June).  Here is an image of her one (of six) spots she had:

[image: staples of my dogs foot]

The blue is a "glue" they use in addition to the staples.  This was a tough spot to heal as it was my dogs rear paw.  It bends a lot naturally when she walks which I thought was possibly causing this appearance.

Like you, I was worried and in my case, I called my vet, to which they had me send this same picture to them.  They didn't seem concerned, but I did end up going back with my dog to be safe.

The vet did not think there was anything wrong, and after some time, my dogs foot has healed up just fine. The main thing is you want to make sure to keep the area as dry as possible (which was difficult to do on rainy days seeing that it was on my dogs foot), and to **not** let your dog lick or scratch it.

Comment: +1. And poor pupper!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a vet, but have lots (and lots!) of experience in treating wounds.

It looks like a good closure healing well. There's one area (T-shaped laceration) where a staple either got loose and fell out, or the skin edges couldn't be approximated well at that one point. In that case, the wound has to heal by [secondary intention](https://teachmesurgery.com/skills/wounds/wound-healing/), which means granulation tissue forms, which then becomes the matrix into which organized epithelium forms. Granulation tissue is red and moist, sometimes oozing clear colorless or pale yellow fluid which can form crusts. That's normal.

All wounds heal with some degree of inflammation (redness and warmth) but wounds healing by granulation tend to have more inflammation than those that are well approximated. It can look like an early infection, but without swelling and pus (as well as an expanding area if redness, swelling and pain), it's not an infection.

Overall, the wound looks like it's healing well. At this point, it's okay to gently start cleaning it once or twice a day with a clean, warm, moist cloth, and soap (real soap) if it looks dirty.

<sub>Scabs are a normal part of wound healing, especially if it was a traumatic wound (as opposed to a clean surgical wound). There are two kinds of scabs: dried blood mixed with serum, which will be a dark brown scab, and one composed of just serum, which will be a light golden brown. Both are normal, and should not be interfered with, unless it looks like there might be an infection starting beneath them. Your dog's wound looks good, and very normal.</sub>